# Analogues of an identity involving quadratic characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer, and suppose $c$ is an integer such that $\gcd(c,d) = 1$. Then the following identity holds:

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \{b \pmod{d} : b^2 \equiv c \pmod{d}  \}\right \rvert = \sum_{\substack{\chi \pmod{d} \\ \chi^2 = \chi_0}} \chi(c).$$

What is the correct analogue for the right hand side when we replace the left hand side with

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \{b \pmod{d} : b^k \equiv c \pmod{d}\}\right \rvert$$

with $k \geq 3$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\gcd(c,d) = 1$ we have

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \{b \pmod{d} : b^k \equiv c \pmod{d}  \}\right \rvert = \sum_{\substack{\chi \pmod{d} \\ \chi^k = \chi_0}} \chi(c).$$

This is not really anything to do with numbers - it works in any finite abelian group, and here we are applying it to the multiplicative group of invertible residue classes mod $c$.

It's a consequence of orthogonality of characters for the group $G/ G^k$.

Comment: Just to elaborate on Will's solution: let $G_d:=(\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $f_d(c)=\#\{ b \bmod d: b^k \equiv c \bmod d\}$ be a function on $G_d$. By orthogonality,
$f_d(c) = \sum_{\chi \bmod q} \overline{\chi(c)} \widehat{f_d}(c),$
where
$$\widehat{f_d}(c)=|G_d|^{-1}\sum_{x \in G_d} f_d(x)\chi(x).$$ Now we can compute $\sum_{x \in G_d} f_d(x)\chi(x) = \sum_{y \in G_d} \chi(y^k) = \sum_{y \in G_d} \chi^k(y)$. If $\chi^k=\chi_0$, this is $|G_d|$. Otherwise, this vanishes by orthogonality.

Comment: ($\widehat{f_d}(c)$ should be $\widehat{f_d}(\chi)$.)